# PHP Packing form data in a variable

Tags: php, variables, http-post, extract

I've got a form and I want to make whatever is written there to be looped ten times after you press the submit button.

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>

       <form>

           <input type="text" name="textbox"> 
           <input type="submit" value="Submit!">

       </form>

       <ul>
           <?php

               $hello = $_POST["textbox"]; //This is most likely wrong

               for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
                   echo "<li>$hello</li>";
               }

           ?>    
       </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

So what I need to do is take the data from the textbox after the submitbutton is pressed, and pack it in a variable. Or maybe that's not necessary? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
      <?php
           if ($_POST["textbox"] != ''){
             for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
                 echo "<li>".$_POST["textbox"]."</li>"; //dont set more variables than you need
             }
           }

       ?>
```

And dont forget to specify method and actoion in your forms

```
 <form method="post" action="">
```

As @Lars Ebert sugested, if your script is ment for public, always validate user input

```
  echo "<li>".htmlspecialchars ($_POST["textbox"])."</li>";
```

Comment: Please use `htmlspecialchars` to escape all user input!

Comment: I dont realy see reason why would you do such think in app like this as it is not for production enviroment. But ok :)

Comment: "Production" is a pretty lousy excuse for sloppy code that doesn't sanitize user input.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this myself, I had forgotten to put the action="hello-world.php" method="post" into the form. Thanks anyways guys!

Answer (score 0):

you need to send a request and rerender the page with PHP

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>

       <form method="POST">

           <input type="text" name="textbox"> 
           <input type="submit" value="Submit!">

       </form>

       <ul>
           <?php

               if(isset($_POST["textbox"])){
                    $hello = $_POST["textbox"];
                   for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
                       echo "<li>$hello</li>";
                   }
               }

           ?>    
       </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: isset() will trigger even if textbox is empty.